# Kafka: Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed

Tags: apache-kafka

I have deployed a kafka broker on a server(kafka-version 2.11-0.10.1.1)  and from my local machine kafka producer is sending a event(in my local kafka-version 2.12-2.0.0), I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
ERROR Error when sending message to topic test-topic with key: null, value: 0 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
```

When i am using the same kafka version, kafka producer is able to sent event. Can anyone explain what is the reason behind this?